# Concatenating 2 Dataframes in R

Tags: r, concatenation

So let's say I have two data frames with identical dimensions and column names:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  1,2,3,
  2,3,4,
  3,4,5
)

y <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  "a","b","c",
  "b","c","d",
  "c","d","e"
)
```

How can I combine them to create this:

```
   # A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     y     z    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1a    2b    3c   
2 2b    3c    4d   
3 3c    4d    5e
```

My initial thought was to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
paste0(x, y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use map2 from purrr:

```
library(purrr)

map2_dfr(x, y, paste0)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     y     z    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1a    2b    3c   
2 2b    3c    4d   
3 3c    4d    5e
```

This could be done without any packages in much the same way:

```
as.data.frame(mapply(paste0, x, y), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In R devel this could be written as:

```
list2DF(mapply(paste0, x, y))
```

Comment: Oh that works great! But what if I wanted to expand on it by adding a separator between the values within each cell? It's not part of the original question, but I'd be curious to see how I could expand on this.

Comment: `map2_dfr(x, y, ~ paste0(.x, "-", .y))`

Comment: Using @G.Grothendiecks answer, in base: as.data.frame(mapply(paste, x, y, sep = "_"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

Also possible in base.

```
setNames(data.frame(sapply(1:3, function(i) paste0(x[,i], y[,i])), 
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE), names(x))
#    x  y  z
# 1 1a 4d 7g
# 2 2b 5e 8h
# 3 3c 6f 9i
```

#### Data

```
x <- structure(list(x = 1:3, y = 4:6, z = 7:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

y <- structure(list(x = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    y = structure(1:3, .Label = c("d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), 
    z = structure(1:3, .Label = c("g", "h", "i"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```